# UITableViewCell imageView problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom leaderboard which I load Game Center profile pictures into a UITableCell that is 32 high.

What happens is when I set the image it displays at around 200x32 then quickly resizes to be a square.  The user sees a flash where the image is distorted before it is shown properly.

What is happening here? How can I fix this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([GCCustomLeaderboard sharedInstance]->nearbyScores.count == 0){
        return nil;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    GCLeaderboardScore *playerScore = [[GCCustomLeaderboard sharedInstance]->nearbyScores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: (%d)", playerScore->alias, (int)playerScore->score];
    cell.imageView.image = playerScore->photo;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Remark: cellForRowAtIndexPath must never return nil. I think that iOS throws an exception if it does.

Comment: I hadnt noticed any issue with that but thanks, I guess itd never actually happen as I specify the correct row count (hopefully)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to resize my images BEFORE putting them in the table.